# How to manage function tobe execute serially or synchronously in nodejs (aws)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I had tried code in nodejs on aws. There are many checking processes are processed. there is one function which is loop through over each data. Final response is outof function which actually consist of variable which is set in loop.

Problem is: When i fired event, it give me response immediately without set in loop. So, i am not getting proper response.

Please help me into this issue. It effects many other scenarios too.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Jagdish

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried.

Comment: We need to see your code to see what you did wrong.